# Firebase Functions:cannot read property 'post_id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do a simple chat app firebase function with my mobile app.This is my current javascript code:

```
'use-strict'

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });

exports.sendCommentNotification=functions.firestore.document("Notifications/{user_id}/Comment/{comment_id}").onWrite((change,context)=> {

    const user_id=context.params.user_id;
    const comment_id=context.params.comment_id;

  console.log(user_id+":"+comment_id);

return admin.firestore().collection("Notifications").doc(user_id).collection("Comment").doc(comment_id).get().then((queryResult)=>{

        const post_id=queryResult.data().post_id;
        const admin_user_id=queryResult.data().admin_id;
        const noti_id=queryResult.data().notification_id;
        const timestamp=queryResult.data().timestamp;
        const post_desc=queryResult.data().post_desc;

        const admin_data=admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(admin_user_id).get();
        const commenter_data=admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();

        return Promise.all([commenter_data,admin_data]).then(result=>{

            const commenter_name=result[0].data().name;
            const commenter_image=result[0].data().image;
            const admin_token=result[1].data().token_id;
            const admin_name=result[1].data().name;
```

My firebase log

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'post_id' of undefined
    at admin.firestore.collection.doc.collection.doc.get.then (/user_code/index.js:20:41)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

`queryResult.data()` is returning `undefined`, which means the document that you queried doesn't exist.  You should check the boolean `queryResult.exists` to see if the document actually exists before trying to access its data.  See the documentation for [DocumentSnapshot](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.17.x/DocumentSnapshot) for more details - that's what `queryResult` is.